# Create Form.MinimumClientSize Property

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

The Windows Forms have `Size` and `ClientSize` Properties. Windows Forms also have a `MinimumSize` property that lets you set the smallest allowed size of the form. I am looking for a way to set the minimum `ClientSize` of a form. I'm new to c# and I am unsure of the best way to do this.

It occurred to me that I could use the `Form.SizeChanged` event to check and restrict the form size but this seemed messy and I am looking for another way of doing it.

Note: **If the form border size is changed I want the Minimum Client Size to be maintained.**

Comment: Override [SetClientSizeCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setclientsizecore)?

Comment: @stuartd I'm looking at the example on the page you linked. Would that be checked every time the size of the control is changed?

Comment: Been a very long time since I did any winforms, sorry. Just thought it might be worth a try.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks anyway. I'll try that out if I can't anything else working.

Comment: Read the remarks [Form.ClientSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.clientsize?view=netframework-4.8) - You just need to set the `MinimumSize` property.

Comment: @JQSOFT I read the remarks and didn't see anything that indicates MinimumSize is what I need. Could you please clarify?

Comment: No, the `MinimumSize` is my answer. The link is to understand the `ClientSize` property and how/where can be used.

Comment: @JQSOFT I want to directly set the minimum ClientSize of the form. This is important because I want the minimum ClientSize to stay the same event if the border style or size changes.

Comment: You can get the size of the borders by subtracting the two sizes. If you listen for WM_SETTINGSCHANGED, you'll know that someone changed the system parameters. I'm not sure you can do this purely in Managed Code, but it's likely possible with a little P/Invoke

Comment: @Flydog57  It's not necessary. The base class is already notified of these changes (User changes in the Windows appearance, custom Themes, Dpi/Font/Language settings etc). When a settings change is acknowledged, the Form performs its Layout and `OnLayout()` is called.

Comment: @Jimi Got it working. Overriding OnLayout worked great. I did run into an issue where it randomly set the form size to 1500x893 - which was quite annoying (I think I was doing arithmetic with Size and ClientSize before the form had initialized those properly). I ended up just making a if/else block for each borderStyle in order to get the size of the border but at least it is working. If you write your suggestion up in a solution I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to set a minimum Size of a Form's Client Area.

The **`Form.MinimumSize`** property sets the minimum size of the Form as a whole, including the current borders, the Caption and the *subtle* internal padding that is applied when the Form is resized and a new Layout is performed (many factors determine this *activity*).

It may be imperceptible, because it's fast (and, usually, nobody cares), but the relation between the Form Size and the Client Size is not constant. It can change when the Form is resized, dragging its borders. Or a System event causes this to happen.

Plus, changing the System settings, in many departments (the properties of the Windows, the Theme, Dpi, Font size etc.), can determine a change in the relations between the Form size and the size of its client area.

The good thing is that the Form is aware of these changes and, when notified of a System event that alters the aspect of Windows in some way, re-performs its layout.
When this happens (and it can happen frequently, always when a Form is resized), the [OnLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onlayout) method is called.

Overriding OnLayout, allows to update values that rely on the Window/Client area measures.

> <sub>➨ It can be interesting to see what happens when System settings,
> affecting the aspect of the Windows, are changed while the application
> is running. In this specific context, how many times the `OnLayout`
> method is called and what the [LayoutEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.layouteventargs) properties are set
> to.</sub>

This all considered, we can create a public **`MinimumClientSize`** Property.
We override **`OnLayout`** and reset the **`Form.MinimumSize`** to the new **`Form.MinimumClientSize`** plus the difference between the **`Form.Size`** and the **`Form.ClientSize`**.

For example, if we need to keep the Client Area size to a minimum of `(500, 500)`:

```
private Size m_MinimumClientSize = new Size(500, 500);

public Size MinimumClientSize {
    get => m_MinimumClientSize;
    set { m_MinimumClientSize = value;
          PerformLayout();
    }
}

protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e) {
    base.OnLayout(e); 
    MinimumSize = m_MinimumClientSize + (Size - ClientSize);
}
```

If we add to the `OnLayout` method:

```
Console.WriteLine($"ClientSize: {ClientSize}");
Console.WriteLine($"MinimumSize: {MinimumSize}");
Console.WriteLine($"Size: {Size}");
```

it becomes clear that the relation between `Form.Size` and `Form.ClientSize` is not always the same.

We could also calculate the difference between Size and ClientSize this way:

```
 var borderSize = new Size(
    (SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width * SystemInformation.BorderMultiplierFactor 
        + (SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width * 2)) * 2, 
    (SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Height * SystemInformation.BorderMultiplierFactor 
        + (SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height * 2)) * 2);

var captionSize = new Size(0, SystemInformation.CaptionHeight);

MinimumSize = MinimumClientSize + borderSize + captionSize;
```

These fixed measures are correct. In normal situations, they provides the same values.
Not always, though. Never, when a Form is resized to its MinimumSize.
Plus, we're only considering a Form with a 3d Border.
Well, we could also override `WndProc`...