# Setting Small Form Width Has Unexpected Results

Tags: c#, forms

I am working on an application which requires sometimes to display an small error message on the desktop. To some reason which I could not identify yet, I was not able to create a window with a width smaller than 136px (but works fine with any larger widths).

I am running VS Community2019, v16.4.5; using .NET Framework 4.8 (.Net Framework 4.6.2 had the same result). Here's a small code example which reproduces my problem:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestWndSize
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static Form MyForm1;
        public static int RqWidth = 120;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            MyForm1 = new Form();
            MyForm1.MouseEnter += MyForm1_MouseEnter;
            MyForm1.SizeChanged += MyForm1_SizeChanged;
            MyForm1.AutoSize = false;
            MyForm1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            MyForm1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            MyForm1.Location = new Point(1400, 100);
            Debug.WriteLine("---  Changing Width to " + RqWidth.ToString());
            MyForm1.Size = new Size(RqWidth, 100);
            Debug.WriteLine("---  Width should be now " + RqWidth.ToString()+"; is "+MyForm1.Width.ToString());
            MyForm1.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

            Application.Run(MyForm1);
        }

        private static void MyForm1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("*** SizeChanged to Width=" + MyForm1.Width.ToString());
        }

        private static void MyForm1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("§§§  Current Width is " + MyForm1.Width.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The debug output is

```
*** SizeChanged to Width=300
---  Changing Width to 120
*** SizeChanged to Width=120
---  Width should be now 120; is 120
*** SizeChanged to Width=136        !!??!!
*** SizeChanged to Width=136        !!??!!
§§§  Current Width is 136       *Execution of MouseEnter*
```

The Width is changed to the requested value but then changed somehow (???) to 136px but only if the requested value is less than 136px.
As the debug output shows the SizeChanged event is executed two times for the undesired size but I do not see any reason why.
Does anybody have an idea what I am eventually missing?

Comment: I am not sure about  what exactly happens in the form initial rendering process, but if you set the new size in the Form.Load event then it stays exactly as you wish

Comment: Yes, Thank you -- Sizing in the Form.Load event did the trick; I am trying this workaround now in my 'true' code.

Comment: About the *why*, read the notes here: [Create Form.MinimumClientSize Property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797946/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi: Since the FormBorderStyle is 'none' we should always have Form.Size exactly equal to Form.ClientSize. And I had verified that the Form.MinimumSize was {0;0}. Isn't it so? (I agree with Steve that my curiosity is not a sufficient reason for in-depth efforts with the source code)

Comment: *(...)including the current borders, the Caption and the subtle internal padding that is applied when the Form is resized(...)*. The *subtle* simile-padding is an invisible border drawn around the Form. This size is returned by `SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width * 2 * 2` (see what that measure is related to). `FrameBorderSize.Width * 2` is usually `8` (it can be different). I.e., when you resize a Form, its bounds are *inflated* by that measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably during the form rendering initialization something changes the size back to a minimum required size. (It seems like the missing borders are not considered).
However you can simply change your size in the Form Load event handler and then the new values are respected

```
private static void MyForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("*** FormLoad to Width=" + MyForm1.Width.ToString());
    MyForm1.Size = new Size(RqWidth, 100);
}
```

Of course you need to manually add the event handler

Comment: Hi, Steve, I tried it in my original code, and it is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Just for curiosity, I had done the same small sample with the standard Visual Editor of my VS19, and that showed the same unexpected sizing for Form widths below 136px. Adding a Load event does the same sizing trick. I am fine now but I still wonder what is causing this strange(?) behaviour.

Comment: I haven't a clear understanding of the process that occurs between the creation of the class (new) and the first meaningful event (Load). Something changes the size there. We could look at the source code to understand but I never find it to worth the time required when you can easily sidestep these intricacies