# Visual Studio form size

Tags: winforms, size

I have a winform, I define the Height to be 436 and the Width to be 470. I then display the mouse position in the title bar to check. What I expected to see is a value of 0 to 469 in the X direction when the mouse is over the form. What I see is that the maximum value in this axis is 459 and that the value changes even when the mouse is some distance from the form. I can bodge this to fit but it would be nice to be able to calculate the required size of the form to fit the controls. The height is not correct either. Could anyone point me to an explanation? This is created using VS 2017 on a Windows 10 PC. This is what the screen looks like as the X axis just stops changing, note the mouse position:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta6KV.png)

Comment: Read the notes here: [Create Form.MinimumClientSize Property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797946/7444103). The size you're setting is the overall size of the Window, including the invisible borders. You probably want to set the ClientSize. That code adds a new Property to a Form, `MinimumClientSize` (mimicking the `MinimumSize` Property), that is updated automatically when some internal or *external* (System) conditions change. You can take it as reference to do something similar (or, well, just set a `ClientSize` value).

Comment: Thanks Jimi, using  **ClientSize** rather than  **Size** worked for me (I was programmatically adding controls and resizing the form).

Answer (score 0):

Forms have invisible borders. You can use margin instead of exact coordinates